# Where to find third party repositories containing the software I want to install?

Tags: package-management, repository, sles, zypper

I'm using sles for my company pc. Now I want to install a new desktop environment.

I run `zypper lr`, below is the output:

```
# | Alias                       | Name                        |Enabled | Refresh
--+-----------------------------+-----------------------------+---------+--------
1 | SLE11-SDK-SP3-Pool          | SLE11-SDK-SP3-Pool          | Yes    | Yes
2 | SLE11-SDK-SP3-Updates       | SLE11-SDK-SP3-Updates       | Yes    | Yes
3 | SLES11-SP3-Pool             | SLES11-SP3-Pool             | Yes    | Yes
4 | SLES11-SP3-Updates          | SLES11-SP3-Updates          | Yes    | Yes
```

So I think only packages included in these repositories I can use zypper to install. Then if I want to install elementryOS DE onto my sles, where can I find the suitable repository?

And I have some other questions:
1. Where to find good unofficial repository which contain the packages I want to install?
2. Is it possible to install packages from other distro, like ubuntu, onto my sles?
3. why the above repositories are related to a specific SLE version? What if my linux distro gets upgraded, do I need to use zypper to add new repositories which are specific to the new version of distro?

Answer (score 0):

A lot of unoffical packages for SLES can be found on [software.opensuse.org](http://software.opensuse.org).

Unfortunately it seems the [elementary package](http://software.opensuse.org/package/elementary) is only available for SLES 12, so you would have to wait for a upgrade to your company pc.

The repositories you listed are the official ones and are related to your current SLES release. On upgrading to a newer SLES the official repositories should be automatically migrated to the correct ones. But if you add your own repositories then you have to migrate those by yourself to match the new SLES release.